# Solving an optimization model for heat integration using GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve the optimization problem regarding heat exchanger network synthesis (equations based on the reference provided below). For this I'm using GEKKO and created the model as provided in this post.

Unfortunately my model has trouble finding a solution. It gives the warning that the model has a negative number of degrees of freedom (-28 to be exact). Could somebody help me in allocating the exact problem in my code?

Thank you for reading my post.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
m.options.IMODE=3   # Steady state optimization

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']


"Defining constants and variables"

# Size of the problem
I = 2   # 2 hot streams
J = 2   # 2 cold streams
K = 3   # 3 temperature nodes

HP = range(I)       #Set of hot streams
CP = range(J)       #Set of cold streams
HU = range(1)       #Set of hot utility (only 1)
CU = range(1)       #set of cold utility (only 1)
ST = range(K-1)     #set of stages: number = k - 1

TIN_i = [443,423]   #Inlet temperatures hot streams 
TIN_j = [293,353]   #Inlet temperatures cold streams
TIN_HU = 450        #Inlet temperature hot utility
TIN_CU = 293        #Inlet temperature cold utility

TOUT_i = [333,303]  #Outlet temperatures hot streams 
TOUT_j = [408,413]  #Outlet temperatures cold streams
TOUT_HU = 450       #Outlet temperatures hot utility
TOUT_CU = 313       #Outlet temperatures cold utility

F_i = [30,15]       #Heat capacity hot streams
F_j = [20,40]       #Heat capacity cold streams


#Constants mostly for cost calculations in objective function
U = m.Const(1)
CCU = m.Const(20)
CHU = m.Const(80)
CF = m.Const(1000)
CF_CU = m.Const(1000)
CF_HU = m.Const(1000)
C = m.Const(1000)
B = m.Const(0.6)

#Constans to apply big M formulation
OMEGA = m.Const(10000)  #Max heat transfer in a single connection
TAU = m.Const(1000)     #Max temperature difference in a single connection


#Defining variables
dT = m.Array(m.Var, (I,J,K-1) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)    #Approach temperature difference
dT1 = m.Array(m.Var, (I,J,K-1) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)   #Approach temperature difference k+1
dTcu = m.Array(m.Var, (I) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)        #Approach temperature difference cold utility
dThu = m.Array(m.Var, (J) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)        #Approach temperature difference hot utility

Q = m.Array(m.Var, (I,J,K-1) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)     #Amount of heat transfer between hot/cold streams in stage k
Qcu = m.Array(m.Var, (I) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)         #Amount of heat transer with hot stream i and cold utility
Qhu = m.Array(m.Var, (J) , value = 1, lb = None, ub = None)         #Amount of heat transer with cold stream j and hot utility

Ti = m.Array(m.Var, (I,K), value = 1, lb = None, ub = None )        #Temperature of hot streams at node k
Tj = m.Array(m.Var, (J,K), value = 1, lb = None, ub = None )        #Temperature of cold streams at node k

z = m.Array(m.Var, (I,J,K-1), value = 1, integer = True )           #Decision veriables (is there a match for heat integration)
zcu = m.Array(m.Var, (I), value = 1, integer = True )
zhu = m.Array(m.Var, (J), value = 1, integer = True )

#Some variables for objective function calculation
Utility_cost = m.Var()
HXfixed_cost = m.Var()
CUfixed_cost = m.Var()
HUfixed_cost = m.Var()
HXarea_cost = m.Var()
CUarea_cost = m.Var()
HUarea_cost = m.Var()

"Defining the equations and objective"

#Heat balance for each stream
m.Equations( (TIN_i[i] - TOUT_i[i] ) * F_i[i] == sum([sum([Q[i,j,k] for j in CP]) for k in ST]) + Qcu[i] for i in HP)
m.Equations( (TOUT_j[j] - TIN_j[j] ) * F_i[j] == sum([sum([Q[i,j,k] for i in HP]) for k in ST]) + Qhu[j] for j in CP)

   
#Heat balance for each stage
m.Equations( (Ti[i,k] - Ti[i,k+1] ) * F_i[i] == sum([Q[i,j,k] for j in CP]) for k in ST for i in HP)  
m.Equations( (Tj[j,k] - Ti[j,k+1] ) * F_i[j] == sum([Q[i,j,k] for i in HP]) for k in ST for j in CP)  


#Assignment of inlet temperatures
m.Equations( TIN_i[i] == Ti[i,0] for i in HP)
m.Equations( TIN_j[j] == Tj[j,K-1] for j in CP)


#Feasibility of temperatures
m.Equations( Ti[i,k] >= Ti[i,k+1] for k in ST for i in HP)
m.Equations( Tj[j,k] >= Tj[j,k+1] for k in ST for j in CP)
m.Equations( TOUT_i[i] <= Ti[i,K-1] for i in HP)
m.Equations( TOUT_j[j] >= Tj[j,0] for j in CP)


#Hot and cold uttility load
m.Equations( ( Ti[i,K-1] - TOUT_i[i] ) * F_i[i] == Qcu[i] for i in HP)
m.Equations( ( TOUT_j[j] - Tj[j,0] ) * F_j[j] == Qhu[j] for j in CP)

#Logical constrains
m.Equations( Q[i,j,k] - OMEGA * z[i,j,k] <= 0 for i in HP for j in CP for k in ST)
m.Equations( Qcu[i] - OMEGA * zcu[i] <= 0 for i in HP)
m.Equations( Qhu[j] - OMEGA * zhu[j] <= 0 for j in CP)


#Approach temperature calculations
m.Equations( dT[i,j,k] <= Ti[i,k] - Tj[j,k] + TAU * (1 - z[i,j,k] ) for k in ST for i in HP for j in CP )
m.Equations( dT1[i,j,k] <= Ti[i,k+1] - Tj[j,k+1] + TAU * (1 - z[i,j,k] ) for k in ST for i in HP for j in CP )
m.Equations( dTcu[i] <= Ti[i,K-1] - TOUT_CU + TAU * (1 - zcu[i]) for i in HP)
m.Equations( dThu[j] <= TOUT_HU - Tj[j,0] + TAU * (1 - zhu[j]) for j in CP)


#Avoiding infinite areas
m.Equations( dT[i,j,k] >= 0.1 for i in HP for j in CP for k in ST)
m.Equations( dT1[i,j,k] >= 0.1 for i in HP for j in CP for k in ST)
m.Equations( dTcu[i] >= 0.1 for i in HP)
m.Equations( dThu[j] >= 0.1 for j in CP)


#Objective definitions
m.Equation( Utility_cost == sum([ CCU * Qcu[i] for i in HP ]) + sum([ CHU * Qhu[j] for j in CP ]) )
m.Equation( HXfixed_cost == sum([ sum([ sum([ CF * z[i,j,k] for k in ST ]) for j in CP ]) for i in HP ]) )
m.Equation( CUfixed_cost == sum([ CF_CU * zcu[i] for i in HP ]) )
m.Equation( HUfixed_cost == sum([ CF_HU * zhu[j] for j in CP ]) )
m.Equation( HXarea_cost ==  sum([ sum([ sum([ C* ( Q[i,j,k] / ( (U * ( dT[i,j,k] * dT1[i,j,k] * (dT[i,j,k] + dT1[i,j,k]) / 2) )**(0.33) ) ) ** B for k in ST ]) for j in CP ]) for i in HP ]) )
m.Equation( CUarea_cost ==  sum([ C * (Qcu[i] / ( U * (dTcu[i] * (TOUT_i[i] - TIN_CU) * (dTcu[i] + ( TOUT_i[i] - TIN_CU ) ) / 2) ** (0.33) ) ) ** B for i in HP ]) )
m.Equation( HUarea_cost ==  sum([ C * ( Qhu[j] / (U * (dThu[j] * (TIN_HU - TOUT_j[j]) * (dThu[j] + (TIN_HU - TOUT_j[j]) ) / 2) ** (0.33) )) ** B for j in CP ]) ) 


m.Minimize(Utility_cost + HXfixed_cost + CUfixed_cost + HUfixed_cost + HXarea_cost + CUarea_cost + HUarea_cost)

m.solve()
```

Source for equations: "Yee, T. F. & Grossmann, I. E. (1990). Simultaneous optimization
models for heat integration/II. Heat exchanger network synthesis.
Computer and Chemical Engineering 1 , 1165."

Comment: Negative degrees of freedom is not necessarily a problem and is common in some cases. Have you double checked your equations? I could not get this to solve even when I relaxed the integer constraint and used IPOPT/BPOPT.

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your model until it solves successfully and then slowly adding detail rather than trying to jump to a complete model.